# Issue with iOS 6 native support on Facebook SDK 3.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I was using the Facebook SDK 3.0 in one of my Apps, and everything was working fine. It was redirecting the user to the Facebook app if installed or to the mobile website if not.

Last week I integrated the new SDK 3.1 to have native integration with the Facebook account. To do this I moved from:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                               allowLoginUI:YES
                          completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    /* My code here */

}];
```

Which is now deprecated to the new:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:permissions
                                   defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                      allowLoginUI:YES
                                 completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
    /* My code here */

}];
```

On iOS 5, nothing changed, perfect. On iOS 6 it worked on my device, but I got some users who report that the system was asking them permissions but they where not able to connect.

And indeed, I have a video, where even clicking "Ok" when the system ask for Facebook permissions, the app do not get access to the account, and is not even registered in the System Preferences.

Here is the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JUHF9KNNg6M

If I remove the account from the system, everything works like previously expected on the Facebook SDK 3.0.

Has someone also encountered this issue? Or do you have any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: @Ludovic i cant  write FBSession in .m file . which framework i have to import for that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you separate your permission requests?

"The Auth Dialog built into iOS 6 gives developers a native way to use Facebook Login in their apps without having to make a fast-app-switch. Note, to use iOS 6 native auth, apps need change the way they request permissions from users - apps must separate their requests for read and write permissions. The Facebook SDK for iOS supports these features and helps developers use them to build apps that work on multiple iOS versions and device configurations."

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/

Comment: Ok, so we have to use openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions: allowLoginUI:completionHandler: to login and ask for the other permissions like write publish_stream in a second time just when we need it.

Answer (score 1):

Can post which permissions you are requesting?

The native Facebook integration on iOS6 has deprecated the `offline_access` permission, and authentication will fail if you attempt to include it. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/ for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be that you didn't specify your bundle identifier on Facebook.
I had that too and once I specified the bundle identifier in developers.facebook.com everything started working fine.