# FBLoginView rejects some users

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sdk, facebook-ios-sdk

I am using the newest Facebook iOS SDK in my project. I have successfully implemented Facebook login using FBLoginView following their own guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/login-ui-control/

This works for most people, however some people are experiencing that they can't login - receiving an error message saying that they need to accept the needed permissions in order to login. Even though they clearly accept these permissions!

I use the same error handling as in the example at the above link (near the bottom of the page) and it seems like the error of type FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled is being triggered.

I cant simulate the error on any of my Facebook accounts neither on the simulator nor my iPhone. However multiple people are experiencing this problem without having anything significant in common. What should I do?

**Update April 24**

My `WelcomeViewController` is the view who handles the Facebook login. In the `.m` file I have the following code for handling permissions:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Facebook login permissions
    loginView.readPermissions = @[@"email"];
    loginView.publishPermissions = @[@"publish_actions"];
    loginView.defaultAudience = FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends;

}
```

**Update April 24 part 2**

With the help from my testers I have localized the problem. Everyone who experiences the login problem has integrated Facebook with iOS - that is they are logged in with Facebook on their iOS (Under Settings->Facebook). As soon as this is disabled - they can log in. Is this a bug in the SDK or how can I handle this?

Comment: Are this your test users or is the app already in the app store? Were you adding new permission-requests after they first logged in with your app? Probably they should remove your app from device, reload a fresh version and it should work. Device reset might be necessary also.

Comment: Luckily these users are test users. Users who have never had the app installed before. I am asking for permissions only at one point in the application - on the view that logs them in. I'll update my post with my code. I am testing using approx 20 test-users and 2-3 are experiencing this problem. Removing the app and reloading a fresh version doesn't seem like an option since I need to know how to avoid this when launching.

Comment: Just as a sidenote: you should ask for "publish_actions" when user first tries to publish something. Not at the login. But this has nothing to do with your problem...

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. Check my update - I think I have narrowed it a lot down now.

Comment: Wow, this is an interesting observation! However: i'm working on FB enabled app right now and thested both variants: logged into FB trough settings and separately without any problems. I use [FBTokenCaching](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.1/class/FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy/) if it helps.

Comment: This looks exactly like the problem you are facing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12687112/653513

Comment: Exatly. I just managed to solve it. I moved my publish permission requests to another view and now it works. Thanks a lot for leading me in the right direction! Feel free to post an answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Answer added. I guess i was wrong in my previous comment that "this has nothing to do with your problem" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in an [accepted answer to a question with a similiar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12687112/653513) you should
only request read permissions at login.

See also [iOS 6 Integration](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/ios-6/) document.

Publish permissions should only be requested when user actually tries to publish something -
this also leads to a better user experience (this way user doesn't get a feeling that your app
will be publishing by itself under his name.

Answer (score 1):

Set sandbox mode to Disabled in your application settings in facebook.[image]